# compute diff between a specific event and the next one

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

I encountered issues when drafting a SQL. The data structure is pretty straight forwards. The ID is an index for user. The event represents something happening now. The time stamp records when this event happens in MS.

The data looks like:

| id | event | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | B | 11 |
| 1 | A | 13 |
| 1 | C | 15 |

I would like to check how to compute the difference of time or duration between event A and the next event. The next event can be anything, and it won't be A again.

For example, for ID 1, we have 2 events, time.A - time.B = 11-10, and time.C - time.A = 15-13, so the result will look like:

| id | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

I am not quite sure how to draft this SQL. Feel free to share any thought.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical use case for `lead()`, which lets you access the "next" row in a sorted partition:

```
select t.*,
    lead(time) over(order by time) - time as duration
from mytable t
```

When there is no "next" row, `lead()` returns `null`, which propagates to `duration`.

If you want to filter on a given `event`, you need to do it in an  outer query (otherwise rows would be filtered out before we can compute the duration), so:

```
select id, duration
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(time) over(order by time) - time as duration
    from mytable t    
) t
where event = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, GMB. Would like to confirm the lag function is for the next records, right? I am a little bit confused about the logic here. We need to access the row with a specific event, and its next row. If we use lag, will it compute the diff between this row and the previous row?

Comment: Should we use lead instead? Thanks.

Comment: @QiangSuper: ah my bad, I misread that part of your question. Yes, `lag()` is for the "previous" row and `lead` is the next one. I updated my answer to use `lead()`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I would like to check what should I do if the data table is quite huge, like billions levels. And you might experience memory issue if using this approach. Do you have any suggestion?